# C#: Getting lowest valued key in a bitwise Enum

Tags: c#, enums, bitwise-operators

I have enum like this

```
[Flags]
public enum Key
{
  None = 0,
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 4
}
```

I have the following

```
Key k1 = Key.A | Key.B | Key.C;
```

I want to get the key in k1 that has the lowest value. How can I do that?

Example:

```
Key k1 = Key.A | Key.B | Key.C; // I want a 
Key k2 = Key.B | Key.C; // I want b
Key k3 = Key.A | Key.C; // I want a
```

Comment: this is your homework, isn't it?

Comment: Also, if this is a bitwise enum, it needs a Flags attribute and generally a None value = 0, and you dont AND bitwise flags when building sets, you OR them.

Comment: @Gjorgji and @NickLarsen: I just realized that and fixed the question, it doesn't make sense unless the Flags attribute is applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Keys key = Keys.b | Keys.c;

var lowest = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys))
    .Cast<Keys>()
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => key.HasFlag(x));
```

Slightly more efficient and .NET 4.0-ish version of the LINQ method.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a bit trick:

```
Key key = Key.B | Key.C;
Key lowest = (Key)((int)key & -(int)key);
```

Comment: @David: Personally, I think it's almost unreadable. It's an interesting curiousity but I hope no-one actually uses it in production code! I'd prefer to use one of the LINQ methods. If someone does use this, I hope they at least comment it with an explanation of what it is doing.

Comment: Yeah, it takes a bit to get it, but I can pretty much guarantee you it's the fastest, and it's so concise.  It's certainly a trade-off readability vs efficiency. That being said, I'd probably put something like this in, and then forget what I did later on down the line.  Nevertheless, it's pretty cool if you're simply talking about the geekiness factor.

Comment: Fantastic and very efficient solution, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
Keys key = Keys.b | Keys.c;

var lowest = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys))
    .OfType<Keys>()
    .Where(x => (x & key) != 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .DefaultIfEmpty((Keys)0);

Console.WriteLine(lowest);
```

Comment: I guess you should add something like `.DefaultIfEmpty((Keys)0)` before first, so it doesn't throw an exception if key is 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 3 values in the enum probably the fastest and easiest is to check them one by one. For a general solution, however, you might want to try to convert the value of `k1` to integer, find the largest power of 2 that divides it and convert it back to Keys enum value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a list of all the values in the
   enum
2. Map those values to some kind of
   comparable data type
3. Compare all the values and keep
   track of the lowest one
4. Convert the lowest one back to the
   enum type

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be an iterative implementation where you test bits. I would do something like this.

```
unsigned int k = (unsigned int) k1;
int pos = -1;
while (k) {
   pos++;
   if (k & 0x1) break;
   k >>= 1;
}
Keys lowestKey = 0;
if (pos >= 0) lowestKey = 0x1 << pos;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you originally posted doesn't make sense: a+b+c aren't prefixed by a type-name, so they won't refer to the enum names they seem to be intended to refer to.

Also, if you use a bitwise AND to combine flags, the result will contain all flags on in *all* paramters - in this case, none.